# Expression Engine Categories

Tags: dynamic, navigation, expressionengine, categories

I have 1 template, and 45 categories. When I click on the link "products" which is my only category group, my side nav shows all of the categories parents and childs, which is good.

I now want to be able to choose one of the categories "central vacuums" for example, and have my side nav turn into all the categories related to "central vacuums" only. I've found a way using segments, but it only seems to allow me to show the child categories within "central vacuums",  not any of the other categories within other parents.

Another example. If I choose a category from my "brands" parent, only products by that brand will show. I then would like to choose another category, and have it limited to both categories.

I hope this makes sense to someone, 
Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to do a category filter, right? Something like http://www.bestbuy.com/site/TV-Video/Televisions/abcat0101000.c?id=abcat0101000 ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout this EE1/EE2 plugin which might do what you need:

**GWcode Categories**

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories

**Examples of what you can do with the plugin are here:**

http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/examples

**Available parameters and variables are here:**

http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation