# How can I show only categories in a side menu that relate to each other?

Tags: expressionengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expression Engine Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200351/expression-engine-categories)

I'm still struggling with categories. I have a parent category with 8 child categories. I also have another category of brands. Is there a way to show all brands in a list that related to the product group selected. WOW, I hope that made sense.

Here's an example...

I have a couple of products that have a parent category selected of "Central Vacuums".

The products are also in the "Accessories" and "Tool Kits" categories, which are children of "Central Vacuums".

Each product has been tagged with a different brand (ie. "BEAM", "Electrolux", "Dyson")

Is there a way to only show "BEAM", "Electrolux", "Dyson" in the Brand list when in the "Central Vacuums" product section because these are brands that have been selected within products in "Central Vacuums". There are dozens of brands, but many of the brands have nothing to do with Central Vacuums.

Very confusing. I apologize. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have two accounts? Or does this guy just happen to have the same question as you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200351/expression-engine-categories

Comment: What do you mean by "tagged with a different brand"?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [Low Seg2Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat) which will grab either category or parent category ID from URL segments which you can then use to filter your channel categories or entries tags.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories , may be just what you're looking for.